# Do Keyboard Hooks always noticeably slow down the keyboard?

Tags: c++, keyboard-hook

I've been playing around with a global keyboard hook using C++, and when the hook is running keyboard input is EXTREMELY slow.  I'm not even doing anything with the hook yet since I'm only playing around with it to learn about hooks.  I'm wondering if it is something wrong with my code or is this just normal for global keyboard hooks?

Here is my code:

DLL file

```
#include<Windows.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include "keyDLL.h"

using namespace std;

LRESULT CALLBACK HookProcedure(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {

        return CallNextHookEx(0, code, wParam, lParam);
    }
```

DLL header file

```
#include "windows.h"

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) LRESULT CALLBACK HookProcedure(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
```

EXE file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "windows.h"

using namespace std;

static HHOOK hhandle;
static HMODULE dllHandle;
HOOKPROC hookProcAddress;

int main()
{
        dllHandle = LoadLibrary(TEXT("C:\\logger\\keyDLL\\Debug\\keyDLL.dll"));
        hookProcAddress = (HOOKPROC)GetProcAddress(dllHandle, "_HookProcedure@12");
        hhandle = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, hookProcAddress, dllHandle, 0);
        Sleep(INFINITE);
}
```

As you can see all I am doing with the hook is CallNextHookEx, so nothing at all.  The result is that I can typ an entire sentence and only the first two words will have made it onto the screen when I'm done and it takes several seconds for the rest to catch up.

Comment: Check if your keystrokes going through hook proc. Long time back I had written similar global hook application where in I had written a function in DLL. The function was calling `SetWindowsHookEx'. The function was then being called from application. It was working perfect. You can give a try.

Comment: So the hook may not actually be working.  I wrote an infinite loop into the callback procedure thinking it would lock up my keyboard.  Nothing happened.  I did print the memory addresses to the screen so I know that the LoadLibrary, GetProcAddress, and SetWindowsHookEx functions are working.